# nginx 400 Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)

Tags: nginx

I've configured nginx as a front-end load-balancer across three nodes of a web application I've constructed. nginx continually returns 400/bad request - invalid hostname errors regardless of the values i use in upstream.server and server.server_name. I've tried localhost and 127.0.0.1 for both of those values and issued requests using matching cURL/Postman requests to no avail.

I've also tried setting the value for server.server_name including the port number to better match the incoming HTTP HOST header to no avail.

nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024; 
}

http { 
  upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

  server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
    }
  }
}
```

cURL requests result in the following (no difference between using localhost and 127.0.0.1).

```
C:\>curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.17.1
< Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2019 14:29:22 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Content-Length: 334
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Comment: That 400 error comes from IIS, not from nginx.

Comment: I don't think that's the case for two reasons.  1) I'm not using IIS.  2) the server header in the response shows 'nginx'
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.17.1

Comment: Exactly what are you using? And how did a message that IIS generates come to appear there, if you aren't using IIS?

Comment: Using HttpListener/http.sys on Windows.  Is there something in the message you see that indicates that it's coming from IIS?  I can see how http.sys could produce a message similar to IIS, but because of the server header I'm of the opinion that it is nginx generating it.  Cheers

Comment: By the way, when I do a request directed to one of the upstream nodes (localhost:8001 as an example) the request succeeds.

Comment: Well, http.sys is close enough. You only see Server: nginx because the response comes _through_ nginx, not from it. It is actually coming _from_ the upstream servers. Now you know where it's coming from and where to look for the problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can see what nginx is submitting on the back side so I can examine its host header?  My app is responding correctly when the host header is set correctly.  The request isn't getting far enough up the stack for my app to see it.

Comment: In the absence of a `proxy_set_header Host` statement, the `Host` header is set to "myapp".

Comment: You just solved my issue.  Can you create a solution response/answer so I can accept it and get you the points you definitely deserve :) <3

Comment: Also if you want to post the answer here I'll accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148312/nginx-http-400-bad-request-invalid-hostname/57149858

Comment: Not that you need the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this configuration:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024; 
}

http { 
  upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

  server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to hijack Michael's points?  :)

Comment: @joelc Yes and No. Actually, it's just a right to the point answer for future reference if somebody googles it. :)

Comment: Awesome thanks Daniel - have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error, but I *am* using nginx in front of IIS. But it was intermittent. It was every other request that failed which was odd.

Turns out I had bound my IIS hostname to a specific IP (as opposed to all IPs) and IIS was load balancing but failing to resolve the other IP.

Telling IIS to bind to all IPs resolved it. Only took a couple hours to figure that out.